# Elasticsearch NEST search query too slow

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I have 7M documents my index. With NEST client i am searching "*" query with this code.

```
    var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");

            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
                node,
                defaultIndex: "evaluation"
                );
            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            var result = client.Search<FtsResult>(s => s
                    .From(0)
                    .Fields(new[] { "id" })
                    .Indices(indexName)

                    .Size(Int32.MaxValue)
                    .Query(q => q
                    .QueryString(qs => qs.OnFields(new[] { "agentText", "customerText" }).Query("*"))
                    )
```

And result elapsedtime is **59.6 sec**. 
In Kibana same query result elapsedtime is just about **4 sec**. Why Nest search query is too slow according to Kibana ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you do this:

```
.Size(Int32.MaxValue)
```

I'm surprised your nodes don't run out of memory with this `Size`. Use a smaller size or, if you really want all documents, use [scan&scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html).